# How do I know if my son has to go to the potty?

Tags: potty-training

My son is showing some slightly little changes, but when I ask him if he does he tells me no.

Comment: Welcome to Parenting! How old is your son? Age can make a big difference!

Comment: Hi Carlesha; As soon as you're able to **[edit your question](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/posts/20637/edit)** with a little more detail, I'll open it back up so you can get some answers. Visible potty "signals" can vary depending on age and a child's mannerisms, so it's tough to give a good answer without additional information.

Answer (score 2):

Use your gamma-ray vision goggles and check their bladder fill level. If somebody lifted the set that came in your parenting handbook (quite common considering their value on the black market) you're just going to have to wing it. Use your intuition. You probably know your child's mannerisms better than they do, so use your best judgment. But also expect to be wrong and treat it as if you're not sure. When it gets to the point that you're pretty sure, call a timeout and ask them a favor. Request they go through the motions and spend the time to go—even if they don't think they need to.

By doing this you'll prevent accidents *and* your child will learn to better understand when they need to go. Judging that takes practice and most won't stop to think about it and analyze whether they could go given the chance. So give them the chance to learn that they can often go even when they didn't *have to go this second or have an accident*.

But also learn to trust them. As they figure it out better and start giving you more reliable yes/no answers start trusting their response and slowly move the onus to them to be right or wrong. But still point out useful break points or places until they learn the drill.

Comment: Hi Caleb, welcome to the site, and thanks for the great answer!  It looks like this might have come from personal experience as a parent - if so, adding a few specific details (such as how long this took) would be very helpful to give other parents an idea of how quickly to expect results!

Comment: @Joe Actually this comes from experience having been parented.

Comment: Well, then it sounds like you have some awesome parent(s)!